# Disabling ThinkPad's Trackpoint button on U

Tags: thinkpad, trackpoint

I recently noticed that my ThinkPad's red trackpoint button keeps moving automatically. I disabled it from BIOS but it still moves whenever I touch the trackpoint. On Windows I managed to turn it off, but how can I turn it off on Ubuntu 22.04?

I am using Ubuntu on Xorg, and this I found this on my input list. I'm not sure which one is my trackpoint.

[image: here is the terminal screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Following this suggestion: https://reinhard.codes/2015/06/24/disabling-the-thinkpad-trackpoint-in-ubuntu/

After opening a terminal window, first type:

```
xinput list
```

You’ll see a list of all the input devices, one of which is the Trackpoint (it’s called “TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint” for me). To disable it, you set the "Device Enabled" property value to 0:

```
xinput set-prop "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint" "Device Enabled" 0
```

[I had to change "IBM" to "Elan". However, you do not have any device with "TrackPoint". Maybe this is because of your BIOS changes?]

Changing this value will not survive a restart, though. There are different ways to achieve this, I edited the .gnomerc file in my home folder. This file is read everytime a Gnome session is started. In the terminal, go to your home folder and execute the following command:

```
echo "xinput set-prop \"TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint\" \"Device Enabled\" 0" >> .gnomerc
```

This will append the command to disable the TrackPoint to the .gnomerc file if it exists or create it if not.